# Issue with marked_for_destruction? in nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've found this strange issue

When I invoke marked_for_destruction? on rails 2.3.5 it works properly and returns true or false but in rails version > 2.3.5 it returns nil

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score -1):

```
mark_for_destruction
```

Marks this record to be destroyed as part of the parents save transaction. This does not actually destroy the record instantly, rather child record will be destroyed when parent.save is called.

Only useful if the :autosave option on the parent is enabled for this associated model.

```
marked_for_destruction?
```

Returns whether or not this record will be destroyed as part of the parents save transaction.

Only useful if the :autosave option on the parent is enabled for this associated model.